# DB::query() Error "Class 'Model\DB' not found"

Tags: query-builder, fuelphp

Hi I'm kinda new to FuelPHP and right now I'm studying some syntax on how to retrieve data using DB::query() builder and I have encountered an error using this code.

Controller:

```
use \Model\Welcome
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller
{
public function action_index()
{
   print_r(Welcome::getuser());
}
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Model;
class Welcome extends \Model {
public static function getuser()
{
$query = DB::query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
return $query->execute();
}

}
```

And it keeps prompting an error saying "ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Class 'Model\DB' not found" what does it mean by 'Model\DB' not found? what did I miss? or what is missing with my code?

And I already configured the database settings on the /config/development/db.php

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem then please accept it. If not then feel free to reply with more information so I can help more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB` class is the in global namespace while your model is in the `Model` namespace so unless you import `DB` with a `use` statement you will have to specify a `\` before the class name `\DB::query()`.

If you do not do either of these then PHP will try and load the `DB` class from the `Model` namespace.